# Give team drive access to file on third party domain. Aka howto share with team drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-shared-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

I am migrating from Google Drive to Google Team Drive.
Some of the files in our shared directory were owned by a third party domain.

I order to move those to the Team Drive I could either

- make a copy of the file and invite the original owner of the outside domain. But this is painful and I would rather not do this.
- share the existing file with the Team drive folder. In other words invite the team drive to the file. However there seems no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We could share files and folders with Google accounts and Google Groups, there is no way to "share a file with a folder" but you could move files owned by you. If the files are owned by other people from the same Organization they should move them.

If the files are owned by people from a third-party organization, AFAIK it's not possible to transfer the ownership of a file, so the file owner can't add the file to a team drive owned by another organization.

From [Share files with Team Drives](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7286514?hl=en)

> ## Move, share, & organize files
>
> You can still share, search, and organize files in Team Drives like
>   your own files in your Drive.
>
> ### Move files from "My Drive"
>
> You can move files into Team Drives the same way you would in your own
>   Drive. [Learn more about moving files](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375091#move_web).
>
> - You may not be able move files owned by other people. If you want to move a file owned by someone else, ask the owner to move it or contact
>     your administrator for assistance.
> - When you share files with someone outside of your Team Drive, they can find the files under "Shared with me". [Learn more about what you can see in "Shared with me."](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375057)
> - If a file is saved in a Team Drive, you can't organize it in more than one folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my opinion it's a pitty that it isn't possible. One should be able to share a document with the organization (=the team drive) instead of just with people and groups. You should be able to add a third party/ other domain document to a team drive. Missing feature.